# Referring a library class available in mobile app from the wear app

Tags: android

In my app, I used the SDK for communicating with the IoT device. The SDK gives the details of IoT device(such as name, id) in a class named XXXDevice.java.

My app also have a wear app version. In the wear app, I need to have a list of IoT device details in order to show the details in the wear app UI. For that, I convert the XXXDevice.java into JSONObject using Gson library and send it to wear app via the Data layer API. In the wear app, I get the JSONObject using the Data Layer API. But I am unable to convert the JSONObject to XXXDevice.java, because the file resides in the SDK jar.

I need to send commands to the IoT device via the mobile app and execute it from the wear app. For that, I need the XXXDevice.java in the wear app to get the IoT device id and it's name. How do I get it in the wear app module?

**Note:** Due to CPU architecture restrictions, I can't add dependency for the SDK in the wear app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should use. Baically send custom messages from your wear to your handheld. Keep the processing (sending commands) still in your handheld which ideally should also be the design as this would centralize your logic.
Anyways check the following link -
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html

Comment: I can't find any solution to my problem from your answer.

Comment: Since you mentioned in your question, that can't use the IOT SDK in your wear module, what I suggested is that let your handheld device all comms with the IOT devices. Use messages between your handheld and wear module for executing commands from wear.

Comment: Could you please revisit my question as I had made some edits?